# Changing the Node Value of an Xml String

Tags: xml, string, basic

I am working with the MapBasic language and I have an XML string which is basically a variable which holds the contents of an xml file as a string.

I want to be able to use the greater than or less than characters within
the node values but because these are reserved characters in XML it returns
an error when I try to use the function MIXmlDocumentLoadXMLString( )

My solution was to parse the string and find the "<" or ">" symbols and replace them with the escape character equivalent : & l t ; AND & g t ; but because XML has tags with the same symbols it modifies the tags as well.

Essentially I want something like this:

```
<R>value < 3 </R>  ->  <R> value &lt; 3</R>
```

not this

```
<R>value < 3 </R>  ->   &lt;R&gt;value &lt; 3 &lt;R&gt;
```

MapBasic is very limited so I cannot use SAX or DOM solutions or any
predefined XML parsers like XMlTextReader etc.. So far I feel like the
problem has to be treated strictly as a string parsing problem.

Any Hints in any language would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but if the input has unescaped less than signs then it is not well-formed XML so it is not XML manipulation that you want to do and XML APIs won't help as you can't parse that input as XML.

Comment: @Martin Honnen Yes your right, the easiest solution would be to have the contributor to the xml make sure to escape those characters to avoid the problem completely.

Comment: Need a way to extract the node value from the string so that any value that has unescaped characters can be fixed accordingly. This should be done in the sense of parsing a string, rather than parsing xml.